# Why this does not show model window in jqwidgets?

Tags: jquery, jqwidget

Following code does not show model window. why?? But it works if i use `$("#filterUserTaskWindow").jqxWindow('show');`  instead of `$("#XUSER01 #filterUserTaskWindow").jqxWindow('show');`  But i need to use `$("#XUSER01 #filterUserTaskWindow").jqxWindow('show');`

```
<div id='XUSER01'>
</div>
<script>
//home tab bar
var UserHomeBar = '<table width="100%" height="35px" id="Homebar" cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px" border="0px"><tr bgcolor="#004A73">';
UserHomeBar = UserHomeBar + '<td>';
UserHomeBar = UserHomeBar + '&nbsp;<input type="button" id="addnewtask" value="Add New Task" />';
UserHomeBar = UserHomeBar + '&nbsp;<input type="button" id="filterUserTask" value="Filter" />';
UserHomeBar = UserHomeBar + '</td></tr></table>';
//home tab grid
UserHomeBar = UserHomeBar + '<div id="userTaskGrid" width="100%" ></div>';
//home tab filter window
UserHomeBar = UserHomeBar + '<div id="filterUserTaskWindow">';
UserHomeBar = UserHomeBar + '<div>';
UserHomeBar = UserHomeBar + '<table>';
UserHomeBar = UserHomeBar + '<tr>';
UserHomeBar = UserHomeBar + '<td><label id="lblfilterUserTaskDateFrom">From Date</label></td>' +
                          '<td> <div id="calfilterUserTaskFromDate"></div></td></tr>';
UserHomeBar = UserHomeBar + '<tr><td><label id="lblfilterUserTaskDateTo">To Date</label></td>' +
                          '<td> <div id="calfilterUserTaskToDate"></div></td></tr>';
UserHomeBar = UserHomeBar + '<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td align="left"><input style="margin-right: 5px;" type="button" id="btnFilterUserTask" value="Filter" /></td>';
UserHomeBar = UserHomeBar + '</tr>';
UserHomeBar = UserHomeBar + '</table>';
UserHomeBar = UserHomeBar + '</div>';
UserHomeBar = UserHomeBar + '</div>';
UserHomeBar = UserHomeBar + '</div>';

$("#XUSER01").append(UserHomeBar);

$("#filterUserTaskWindow").jqxWindow({
width: 300,
height: 150,
autoOpen:false
});
$("#XUSER01 #filterUserTask").click(function() {
        var xx=$("#XUSER01").find('*')
        var flag=0;
        for(i=0;i<xx.length;i++){
             if(xx[i].id=='filterUserTaskWindow')
                 flag=1
        }
        if(flag==1)
            alert('found');
        else
            alert('not found');
        $("#XUSER01 #filterUserTaskWindow").jqxWindow('show');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To display a jqxWindow, as far as I know, you should call "open", not "show".